# groupby() with sort_values() syntaxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to make a groupby and after  a sort_values

```
Depuis_2013 = pd.DataFrame(aide1, columns=['Pays','Année','Aide_kg'])

Depuis_2013_aide  = Depuis_2013.groupby (('Pays') ['Année']).sum().sort_values(by= "quantite_aide", ascending=False).head(7)
```

***and I have got this error***

```
SyntaxWarning: str indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
SyntaxWarning: str indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5680/565621470.py:3: SyntaxWarning: str indices must be integers or slices, not str; perhaps you missed a comma?
  Depuis_2013_aide  = Depuis_2013.groupby (('Pays') ['Année']).sum().sort_values(by= "quantite_aide", ascending=False).head(7)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_5680/565621470.py in <module>
      1 Depuis_2013 = pd.DataFrame(aide1, columns=['Pays','Année','Aide_kg'])
      2 
----> 3 Depuis_2013_aide  = Depuis_2013.groupby (('Pays') ['Année']).sum().sort_values(by= "quantite_aide", ascending=False).head(7)

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Please, consider adding your desired output and, more importantly, your current input(or at least a shareable part of your dataframe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how to use groupby and sort

```
data = {'column1' : ['American', 'American', 'Mexican'], 'column2' : [1, 1, 2], 'column3' : [1, 1, 2]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df = df.groupby('column1')[['column2', 'column3']].sum().sort_values(by= "column1", ascending=False)
```

I added my own dataframe since you are a new contributor and might not know how to create examples

In this example you can see I create a df with some data then group by the 'column1' and get the sum of 'column2' and 'column3' once I have the sum I use the sort_values function to sort by 'column1'

You should be able to plug in your own data and get the desired results.

Comment: I apply your dataframe

Aide_a = aide1

za = pd.DataFrame(Aide_a)

za = za.groupby('Pays')[[ 'Aide_kg']].sum().sort_values(by= "Pays", ascending=False).head(30)

za

I woul like order by ascending = false

Answer (score 0):

[This is the Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCV4j.png)

```py
Aide_a = aide1
za = pd.DataFrame(Aide_a)

za = za.groupby('Pays')[[ 'Aide_kg']].sum().sort_values(by="Aide_kg",
                                             ascending=False).head(30)
```

I would like to order by ascending = false and now is OK